# How can I stop my ClickOnce install from requiring Newtonsoft.Json v4.5 in the GAC?

Tags: wpf, json.net, nuget, clickonce

We have a ClickOnce deployment of a WPF desktop application, and recently installed the Newtonsoft.Json version 6.0.8 NuGet package.

After making this change and publishing the ClickOnce deployment, users can't run the update, because of this error message:

[image: The error message shown when updating the application]

The first thing that strikes me as odd is the dependency on version 4.5.0.0, when I'm using version 6.0.8.

Ignoring that for a moment, everything I've found online suggests that I ensure the reference is set to copy local, and that in the *Application Files* dialog of the *Publish* settings, I make sure that the assembly is set to *Include* and *Required*.

I've checked these and found that they are already correct:

[image: Reference properties]

[image]

So I'm a bit stumped. How could the ClickOnce application be requiring an older version of this assembly be installed into the GAC?

Any ideas beyond the obvious would be massively appreciated!

**UPDATE 1**

I don't know how useful this is, but I've found that if I set the reference to not copy locally (making it a prerequisite instead of an include), and publish again, then when I install the application, I get the same error, but for the correct version:

[image: Same error message but for version 6]

**UPDATE 2**

Interesting. If I uninstall the NuGet package from the project (which removes the reference), and then make sure it's not in the ClickOnce package at all, I still get the original error. This must mean that I'm referencing something that references Newtonsoft.Json version 4.5.0.0??

**UPDATE 3**

So I found the referenced project that is causing the error. But that project has Newtonsoft.Json version 6.0.8 installed, so I still don't understand where this version 4.5.0.0 dependency comes from.

**UPDATE 4**

The battle continues. I've managed to move some responsibility around such that there is no Newstonsoft.Json reference in the WPF application or any projects it references, and none of them have the NuGet package installed. I can now publish and install the package, but when I **run** the application, I get this exception:

[image: Application startup exception]

**UPDATE 5**

Well, I've found the cause, and it's this line of code in the main view model:

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Common/MyApiMethod", data).ContinueWith(t => t.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
```

As soon as I go anywhere near the PostAsJsonAsync method, I get the error message shown above, in update 4. However, that extension method is part of the HttpClientExtensions class, which lives in the System.Net.Http.Formatting assembly.

So I guess the question is why that assembly expects the version 4.5.0.0 GAC install, and why this hasn't come up before, but most importantly - how can I prevent this reliance on the GAC?

**UPDATE 6**

I just spotted that the assembly mentioned above is referenced via this path ... C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC 4\Assemblies\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll ... so it's obviously an ASP.NET MVC assembly. So I guess I'm faced with either installing latest MVC as a NuGet package (which seems really daft for a WPF project) or change the method for connecting to Web API to an alternative (maybe preferable).

**SOLUTION**

Zache's answer is a concise summary of the problem. The PostAsJsonAsync method belongs to System.Net.Http.Formatting, which is an ASP.NET MVC extension assembly. This in turn relies on an old version of NewstonSoft.Json, hence the GAC dependency.

I removed the reference to System.Net.Http.Formatting and replaced the code that connects to the server, which now uses an up-to-date Newtonsoft.Json to serialize the data being sent to the server.

This serialized data is then packaged into a StringContent object and sent to the server, and the response can be deserialized from JSON to the requested type.

```
var data = new { /* Anonymous object definition*/ };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.Unicode, "application/json");

try
{
    var response = await client.PostAsync("api/MyController/MyMethod", httpContent).ContinueWith(t => t.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode());
    var returnData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var result = returnData;
    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
```

Comment: Get rid of System.Net.Http.Formatting and try [RestSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp) instead. It's pretty awesome for basic http requests.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds promising - I'll have a look!

Comment: I had a brief play with RestSharp but couldn't get on with it. To be fair, I was drowning in problems and under a lot of time pressure at the time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking up *System.Net.Http.Formatting* we find [this](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/System.Net.Http.Formatting) nugetmusthaves-page. Which in turn tells us that the assembly has a dependency which is *Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2.2 Client Libraries* that in turn requires *JSON.net*.

How did you add the *System.Net.Http.Formatting* assembly to your solution? Did you use NuGet? Try removing it and installing it via NuGet instead. That should probably work :)

Comment: It was quite a while ago now, but it's most likely that I cribbed the code from somewhere, and then Resharper offered to add the missing reference. The MVC files in Program Files would have been installed there when Visual Studio was installed.

Comment: But did you try adding them via nuget?

Comment: Would rather not add MVC to the WPF client - seems overkill. Have marked this as the correct answer, because it explains the error. I've removed that reference and changed how the service is called, serializing the JSON object to a StringContent object instead.